# Why is this Rust slower than my similar Python?

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust program (rustc 1.0.0-nightly (44a287e6e 2015-01-08 17:03:40 -0800)):

```
use std::io::BufferedReader;
use std::io::File;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("nc.txt");
    let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));
    let lines: Vec<String> = file.lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()).collect();
    println!("{}", lines[500]);
}
```

According to the example at http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/ the above is the way to pull the lines of a file into a vector of strings. I've thrown in the output of the 500th line.

To solve the same task in Python I've written the following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

def main():
    with open('nc.txt', 'r') as nc:
        lines = nc.read().split('\n')
    print("{}".format(lines[500]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the compiled Rust and time it I get this:

```
rts@testbed $ time ./test
A declaration of independence by Kosovo will likely bring a similar declaration from Georgia's breakaway Abkhazia region, which Russia could well recognize.

./test  1.09s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 1.120 total
```

Running the Python gives:

```
rts@testbed $ time ./test.py 
A declaration of independence by Kosovo will likely bring a similar declaration from Georgia's breakaway Abkhazia region, which Russia could well recognize.
./test.py  0.05s user 0.03s system 90% cpu 0.092 total
```

I know that `println!` is a macro which expands to the more complex

```
::std::io::stdio::println_args(::std::fmt::Arguments::new({
    #[inline]
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    static __STATIC_FMTSTR: &'static [&'static str] = &[""];
    __STATIC_FMTSTR
},
&match (&lines[500],) {
    (__arg0,) => [::std::fmt::argument(::std::fmt::String::fmt, __arg0)],
}));
```

Still, that doesn't seem like the sort of thing that would cause more than a second of additional execution time. Are these snippets of code not, in fact, similar? Have I misinterpreted the most efficient way to read lines into a vector and output one of them?

For reference `nc.txt` has the following properties:

```
rts@testbed $ du -hs nc.txt 
7.5M    nc.txt
rts@testbed $ wc -l nc.txt
   60219 nc.txt
```

Comment: Use `strace` or `ltrace` to find out what is happenning

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on (`rustc -O foo.rs`)?

Comment: Yes, it is likely that you are not using optimizations. If you're using Cargo, run `cargo build --release`.

Comment: FWIW, compiling your program with optimizations brings the time down to the python version: `./rust  0,06s user 0,01s system 98% cpu 0,065 total`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570773/why-is-my-rust-program-slower-than-ruby-equivalent
This might help, just compile with optimizations

Comment: Compiling with optimizations is definitely the answer. Thanks, all. `./test  0.03s user 0.02s system 88% cpu 0.054 total`

Comment: You should answer your own question, so that other users don’t have to seek through the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Build it with optimization flags.

```
cargo run --release
```